# Interrogative negative passive

Tags: grammar

Is it grammatically correct?:

> What letter isn't written on the board?

for the structure of Interrogative negative passive?

Comment: Yes, it is correct grammatically. However, writing a letter on the board is odd. Do you mean writing a letter on the board, whiteboard or blackboard? Or do you mean posting a letter  on the (bulletin) board??

Comment: On the whiteboard.

Comment: Ok, well, then it's fine. letter as in A, B and C, not a missive, right?

Comment: "Which letter", since it is a choice within a defined group.

Answer (score 1):

> What letter isn't written on the board?

is grammatically correct and, at the same time, ambiguous.

"letter" can mean:

- letter of the alphabet;
- text on a paper;

"board" can mean:

- writing board (i.e. blackboard or whiteboard);
- bulletin board
- any thin flat (usually) rectangular, classically made of wood.

With physical objects, the verb "written" would exclude the bulletin boards, but considering the electronic "boards" the exclusion is no longer possible.

On the other hand, "what" suggests letters of the alphabet, rather than texts.

So examples of sentences without confusion could be:

> Which letter of the alphabet isn't **written** on the whiteboard?

or:

> Which message is not **posted** on the bulletin board?